# Error Modifying Intel Powerclamp Ratio?

Tags: kubuntu, 17.10, konsole

Following the Intel Powerclamp instructions (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/thermal/intel_powerclamp.txt), I tried setting the ratio using their recommended Konsole entry: `sudo sh -c "echo 15 > /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device80/cur_state
"` This gave an error : `sh: 1: cannot create /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device80/cur_state: Directory nonexistent`

**EDIT 0:**
I ran the commands and got:

> `sarah@ConvergentRefuge:~$ ll /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device*
>   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb  9 09:01 /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device0 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device0/
>   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb  9 09:01 /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device1 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device1/
>   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb  9 09:01 /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device2 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device2/
>   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb  9 09:01 /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device3 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device3/
>   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb  9 09:01 /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device4 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device4/
>   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb  9 09:01 /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device5 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device5/
>   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb  9 09:01 /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device6 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device6/
>   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb  9 09:01 /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device7 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device7/
>   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb  9 09:01 /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device8 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device8/
>   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb  9 09:01 /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device9 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device9/`

But when I ran `sudo sh -c "echo 15 > /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device0/cur_state"`
 I got an I/O Error.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is on the right track but leads to the wrong solution in my case. To track down missing files or directories use this technique:

```
$ ll /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb  7 04:33 /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device0 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device0/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb  7 04:33 /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device1 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device1/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb  7 04:33 /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device2 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device2/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb  7 04:33 /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device3 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device3/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb  7 04:33 /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device4 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device4/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb  7 04:33 /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device5 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device5/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb  7 04:33 /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device6 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device6/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb  7 04:33 /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device7 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device7/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb  7 04:33 /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device8 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device8/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb  7 04:33 /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device9 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device9/
```

On my system cooling devices are numbered `0` to `9`. There is no number `80` which you are trying to access.

Then to see the value of all 9 `cur_state` files use:

```
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device*/cur_state
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
-1
0
```

Interesting to note that `cooling_device8` is set to `-1`. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

One of the directories in your path to `cur_state` either does not exist or has a broken symbolic link. It is most likely `cooling_device80`